# Will RODC at remote site affect the main DC with azure syncing

Tags: azure, remote

We need to install RODC (Read only Domain Controller) at all our remote locations. Currently our infrastructure is we have a domain controller on premise and Azure connected with Azure AD connect. Azure is only using for O365 password synchronization for O365 email users.
Does RODC affect AD or Azure users' logins if we implement it to our remote sites as the remote site users will use the local RODC?

The RODC will not have Internet access and it will only connect to the Main DC in head office.

Comment: That depends a bit on the capacity of the main dc and how many resources it has left.  If the dc is already reaching max capacity now then adding the RODC might have some impact, if the main dc has enough resources available it won't be a problem. But I would suggest to be safe adding a secondary DC in the main office to make sure adding the RODCs has no impact.  One DC is also not recommended in terms of business continuity